# RegularExpressionValidator to limit input length with no limitations on character types

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex, validation

I'm trying to use a `RegularExpressionValidator` to validate a `TextBox` input length. I have it working, but it only accepts letters and numbers. I'd like to allow **any** characters, with the only check being there are no more than 25 characters.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="MenuLabel" runat="server" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9]{25}$" ID="MenuLabelVal" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Menu Label must be no longer than 25 characters." ControlToValidate="MenuLabel"  />
```

Regular expressions are not my strong suit, so can someone tell me how I modify `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{25}$` to represent *any characters* up to 25 times rather than just alpha-numeric.

**Note 1:** I already have a `RequiredFieldValidator` in place to ensure 1 or more characters.

**Note 2:** I know I could just use the `MaxLength` property on the TextBox, however this form is also for editing existing data, and I do not want it to simply truncate existing records when editing. I'd prefer to implement a validator which makes it obvious for users editing existing data they need to shorten the value, rather than the form truncating without the user realizing.

**Note 3:** I'm open to alternate solutions, such as a custom validator, as long as it relies only on client-side validation. I don't have access to the code-behind to write a custom validate handler on the server.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
.{1,25}
```

should limit the value to any char 1 to 25 times. Not sure how this will deal with unicode input though - it may count multi-byte chars as a single char, so be careful if you are using this to limit for a database

possibly you might want `^.{1,25}$` but I think even this simple version should work

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try. The current form has no validation, just a MaxLength set on the TextBox for 125, so at least it has a hart limit on it.

Comment: The second version should be faster

Comment: Ok I've tried both `.{25}` and `^.{25}$`. Both show valid with either 0 or 25 characters. 1 through 24 validate as invalid. Should it be `^.{1,25}`?

Comment: Ok, so `^.{1,25}$` seems to be the best option. Without the ends-with clause, the validation was doing some strange things. I updated your answer, hope you don't mind. The original of .{25} only validated when exactly 25 characters were used. I was looking for the range.

Answer (score 4):

If you use a custom validator, then you could do something like this:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="MenuLabelVal" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateFieldLegth" ErrorMessage="Menu Label must be no longer than 25 characters." ControlToValidate="MenuLabel" EnableClientScript="true"  />
```

And your javascript would be something like this:

```
<script>     
    function ValidateFieldLegth(sender, args) {
        var v = document.getElementById('<%=MenuLabel.ClientID%>').value;
        if (v.length > 25) {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
        else {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It actually works quite well, but I chose to stay with the regular expression approach since from a markup standpoint is was simpler than introducing extra scripting. I +1'd it anyway as completely valid approach.