# Range validator not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

i am trying to put asp.net Required Field Validator and Range Validator but only Required Field Validator works not range. why ?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCNIC" runat="server" CssClass="textField_width"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCNIC" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ForeColor="#FF3300" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="Complaints">CNIC is Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:RangeValidator
                                ControlToValidate="txtCNIC"
                                MinimumValue="14"
                                MaximumValue="16"
                                Type="String"
                                ValidationGroup="Complaints"
                                EnableClientScript="false"
                                Text="CNIC can not be longer than 15 characters"
                                runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSave"  CssClass="btn btn-success"  runat="server" Text="Save" 
         ValidationGroup="Complaints" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

Comment: What is the result you are currently getting?

Comment: You've disabled client-side validation with `EnableClientScript="false"`... remove that or set it to `true`.

Comment: If you are trying to check the length of the inputted string then you would probably be better off using a `RegularExpressionValidator` to do this.

Comment: @cory: no effect, same issue

Comment: @Cory Disabling client side validation does not disable the validation itself. Assuming he is doing validation correctly, it would still be firing server side when `Page.IsValid` is called.

Answer (score 1):

ASP `RangeValidator` is meant to validate that the input is within a **given range**, whereas in your case it seems you want to validate the **input length**.
To do this, you can do something like this:

In your page, replace the `RangeValidator` by a `CustomValidator`:

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" id="txtCNICValidator"
     controltovalidate="txtCNIC" ClientValidationFunction="validateCnic"
     errormessage="CNIC must be exactly 15 characters long!" />
```

And add the corresponding validation function in your javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function validateCnic(sender, args) {
    args.IsValid = (args.Value.length == 15);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Indeed `RangeValidator` is the wrong control but I'd probably use a `RegularExpressionValidator` in it's place as you get all the client/server stuff thrown in for free. Also in your example you could just `e.IsValid = e.Value.Length == 15`, saves a few keystrokes and IMO doesn't hurt readability?

Comment: @DaveParsons You're right, edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Custom valiator that u provided above is not working

Comment: @DaveParsons regarding the use of a `CustomValidator`, it actually allows the validation to occur on the client side

Comment: @user3518032 I've edited my answer to perform the validation on the client side, can you give it a try?

Comment: @YannickBlondeau: Indeed but you are required to write both the client and server functions yourself, whereas with the `RegularExpressionValidator` the frameworks does all that for you - you *just* provide the regular expression.

Comment: @DaveParsons Ah OK, I thought the client side function alone would be sufficient... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Like DaveParsons mentioned in the comments, I also feel like a `RegularExpressionValidator` would be the best approach here.

You can configure it to validate a specific length range as evidenced in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11263759/1946412).